# BackboneJS, RequireJS How to include .LESS

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, less

How can I get RequireJS to load .LESS? Until now it has been nothing more than a pain in the a.. to get it to run.

In my backbone config file i have:

```
require.config({

paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery',
    backbone: 'lib/backbone/backbone',
    handlebars: 'lib/handlebars/handlebars',
    text : 'lib/requirejs-text/text',
    less: 'lib/less/less',
    lodash: 'lib/lodash/lodash.min'
}

});
```

and on my index page i have

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.less')?>" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/admin.less')?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

it seems they get loaded, but for example all my `@border`, `@background-dark`, `@grey` etc etc files don't work...

so, does anybody know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://github.com/guybedford/require-less) plugin for requirejs. It also works fine with r.js optimizer.

Comment: Is there a more simple solution for this?

Comment: @SHT If you want to load less with requirejs, then I think there is no more simple solutions. It is simple enough in usage. It's getting a bit harder, if you are planning to use it with optimizer.

Comment: hmm its a quite confusing setup but apparently thats the way to go... :s